# Select element not in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop, sublist

I understand how one would normally select an element not in a list. With the code I have though, that method doesn't seem to work.

So I have a text file containing the following data:
Min: 5,6,1
Max: 5,6,1
Avg: 5,6,1

I want to select only the numbers from the file and create a list from them. I've tried doing it by type but that doesn't work because all the elements in the list are counted as strings.

So I put together the following code:

```
inFile_test = open('in_test.txt','r')
while True:
    lines = inFile_test.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = [lines[0][0:3] , lines[1][0:3] , lines[2][0:3]]
        print str(words)
        values = []
        for element in lines:
            if element not in words:
                values.append(element)
            print str(values)

    else:
        break
```

And I get the following output:

```
['Min', 'Max', 'Avg']
['Min: 5,6,1\n']
['Min: 5,6,1\n', 'Max: 5,6,1\n']
['Min: 5,6,1\n', 'Max: 5,6,1\n', 'Avg: 5,6,1']
```

I have a sense that there's something wrong with my list structure that's preventing the code from running properly but I'm not sure what it is.

If not that, suggestions on a better way to select just the numbers from my text file would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want as your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be frank, your code is a mess. Why are you wrapping your logic in a while-loop? It is going to terminate after the first iteration anyway.

Simplify by using `file.read` instead of `readlines`:

```
with open('in_test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Then, just do the following:

```
>>> data
'Min: 5,6,1 Max: 5,6,1 Avg: 5,6,1'
>>> [int(c) for c in data if c.isdigit()]
[5, 6, 1, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('in_test.txt',sep=r":|,",header=None,index_col=0).T
```

If you want to read line by line

```
with open('in_test.txt','r') as inFile_test:
    for line in inFile_test:
        word,numbers = line.split(":")
        numbers_as_float = [float(num) for num in numbers.split(",")]
        print(word,numbers_as_float)
```

Comment: use a `with` block to make sure your file closes, not `try ... except`